# Creating multiple Firebase user accounts at the same time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create multiple user accounts at the same time, so I put

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userObj.email, password: userObj.password, completion: {
        (user, error) in
```

in a for loop passing different emails, but it only creates accounts for the last email passed. For example, three accounts with this email: a@a.com if this was the last email passed in a 3-round loop. How can I create multiple accounts at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure that userObj.email is being changed over each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication SDK for iOS is meant to only create an account for the current user. It is not meant to create accounts for other users, nor to create multiple accounts. If you want this, consider using the Firebase Admin SDK.

If you *must* run this code in the iOS app, wait for each call to be completed before calling `createUser` again.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email1, password: password1) { (user, error) in
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email2, password: password2) { (user, error) in
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email3, password: password3) { (user, error) in

    }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I should probably make a method that calls itself after each successful createUser until the last element in an array of whatever.

Comment: @fullMoon Also, calling createUser logs out the current user which can also cause other issues depending on your use case.